# QGIS Gratuated Symbology gives differents results on every classification with Natural Breaks (Jenks)

Tags: qgis, symbology, classification

When styling a polygon layer using the Graduated styling and the Natural Breaks (Jenks) mode, QGIS is classifying the data with different values.

So every time I click on "Classify" the values are different.

Why?

***EDIT 1:***

Using QGIS 3.4.4 on Windows 10

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Ubuntu 18.04, 3.4.4-Madeira - can you add operating system and qgis version

Comment: See Edit 1 for the info

Comment: Using the same dataset, ArcMap complained that the number of features was too big and that I could increase the sample size if I want to. So maybe QGIS is taking a different sample of the data everytime I click on "Classify"?

Comment: I can reproduce with QGIS 2.18 if there are "many" features. In my test, it occurred when more than 3001 features were to be classified in 5 classes.

Comment: Testing with 21426 polygon I got the same behavior (different value after each classification), the number of classes didn't matter.  QGIS 3.4.1 on window 7

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/530397c1683cc787ef90bc27e2d958779ed0d754/src/core/symbology/qgsgraduatedsymbolrenderer.cpp#L720), QGIS will take the exact values if there are up to 3000 features. 
Otherwise, it will take the largest between 3000 **random** features or a **random** 10% of the data.

Comment: And if you have for example 4000 features, does QGIS uses 10% of 4000 features (so 400) or it uses up to 3000 features?

Comment: it will take the largest between 3000 features or a random 10% of the data

Comment: Ah! I read it wrong the first time.

Comment: @GobTron I have clarified it. It will take 3000 random features